# How to start a debug session using chromium browser in VSCode in Windows

Tags: windows, debugging, visual-studio-code, chromium

I'm trying to start a debugging session in VSCode using Windows OS and using chromium browser. I was unable to start the debugging session with the configuration I had.

Below is the configuration I already added.

```
{
   "version":"0.2.0",
   "configurations":[
      {
         "type":"chrome",
         "request":"launch",
         "name":"Launch Chromium against localhost",
         "url":"http://localhost:4200/#",
         "webRoot":"${workspaceFolder}/wwwroot",
         "runtimeExecutable":"C:/Users/{userName}/AppData/Local/Chromium/Application/chrome.exe",
         "runtimeArgs":[
            "--new-window",
            "-user-data-dir=\"/${workspaceFolder}/DevProfile\"",
            "--remote-debugging-port=9222",
            "--disable-background-networking"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Please help me in correcting the debugging configuration. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: "I was unable to start the debugging session" Why are you unable? [Edit] this question and share what results you get. Also, why you are there, why not format the code appropriately so it is readable.